# Include namespace in Rails 3.1 console

Tags: namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3.1, irb

My Rails 3.1 application is completely implemented inside a namespace. When I open the Rails console I would like to be able to directly access identifiers inside my namespace. I would like not to have to type the full qualified names everytime.

Instead of

```
Aef::Newman::HandledAddress
```

I would like to write

```
HandledAddress
```

Including the namespace inside the console like the following does not help for some reason:

```
include Aef::Newman
```

Comment: If using Pry, I can simply call Pry.start(Aef::Newman). I've found no way to do that in IRB so far.

Comment: Or, inside pry session, Unix-style `cd Aef::Newman`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an irb sub-session, "moving into" the desired namespace by typing

```
irb Aef::Newman
```

[See here](http://old.nabble.com/%27move-into%27-a-module%27s-namespace-in-irb-td24125387.html) and the IRB documentation, [here](http://rubycentral.org/pickaxe/irb.html)

Comment: Is it possible to make "rails console" move into the namespace automatically?

Comment: Seems not to be possible. I switched to `pry`, where this is possible.

Comment: Good stuff, I was getting annoyed to always type my engine name when working with a Rails engine