# How to access a namespace method in Ruby console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, rails-console

Found this post [Include namespace in Rails 3.1 console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615856/include-namespace-in-rails-3-1-console) but it doesn't seem to work.

The following lib/task defined and it works from the command line: `rake namespace_name:task_name`.

How to call a method `method_name` in `namespace_name` from within the console, without calling the task?

```
rails console
namespace_name::task_name
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'namespace_name' for main:Object

irb namespace_name
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'namespace_name' for main:Object
```

Working in Rails 3.07, Ubuntu.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but consider using [rake-sh](https://github.com/jugyo/rake-sh) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call a method defined inside a `.rake` file you do something similar to what @Nate said, but instead of calling the raketask, call the method:

```
require 'rake'
Rake.load_rakefile 'lib/tasks/namespace_name.rake'
method_name(arg1, arg2)
```

It feels kind of strange that you don't need to specify the namespaces but I just tried this and it worked.

Comment: What is the difference between `Rake.load` and `load`?

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing two different kinds of "namespaces" - Ruby modules can perform the task of "namespacing" Ruby code; Rake namespaces are only used within Rake to categorize tasks, and they don't create a module namespace.

The page you linked only works with Ruby module namespaces.

If you want to call Rake tasks from the Rails console, it's a bit more involved...

```
require 'rake'
Rake.load_rakefile 'lib/tasks/namespace_name.rake'
Rake::Task['namespace_name:task_name'].invoke
```

Or just call it on the command line from within the Rails console -

```
%x[rake namespace_name:task_name]
```

Comment: require 'rake' returns `nil`. Rake.load_rakefile throws `NoMethodError: undefined method 'load_rakefile' for Rake:Module`

Comment: Also, I want to call a ***method*** within the namespace, ***not a rake task***.

Comment: Also, the first line you posted runs a Rake task - `rake namespace_name:method_name` is really `rake namespace:task`.  Under the covers this may call a `namespace:method` but there's no guarantee of this - can you post the contents of the rake task file?

Comment: require returning `nil` just means that the library is already loaded... you'd get a LoadError if it couldn't be found.  But then `NoMethodError` on `load_rakefile`... Can you post the versions of Ruby and Rake you are using?

Comment: You're right. `rake namespace_name:method_name` should be `rake namespace_name:task_name`. How do you call a method within a namespace without calling a task?